# How to save table content permanently

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am an absolute beginner in javascript. I tried to make an table which can save the content i type in it. I just got the total opposite from what i wanted the table deletes the content everytime i refresh the website.

Basically my question is what i have to change so i can save the data permantly and it dont vanish everytime i refresh the webpage. Also it would nice to know what i did wrong. I already tried to change some things but it got just worse

Here is some example code for you:

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });


});



function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>mail</td>
        <td>phone</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="mail" name="mail"  class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control"/>
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: You'll need a database or a different storage mechanism.

Comment: You need to use some kind of database if you want to persist data between requests,] alternatively  you can save  the tabel data client side using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) api

Comment: Sure a database thank you all!!!

Comment: so as an example i can just make a button wich saves the input to the database right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `localStorage` object, which stores data with no expiration date. This data will not be deleted when you refresh the page or even close the browser.
In order to do that, you first need to create the function which will save the data into `localStorage`.

```
function save_data(){
    let table_data = []
    $('.form-control').each(function() { table_data.push( $(this).val() )});
    localStorage.setItem('table_data', JSON.stringify(table_data));
}
```

This function iterates through all table cells and saves its content into `table_data` array.
Then `table_data` array is converted into `String` with `JSON.stringify` and saved in `localStorage`.
This function should be executed every time you add, remove or edit one of the rows.
In order to do that we need to create new event handlers:

```
$('tbody').on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {save_data()});
$('tbody').on('change', '.form-control', function() {save_data()});
```

The first one triggers `save_data` function every time a row is created or removed.
The second one saves data whenever the table's content is modified.

We also need a function for loading data from `localStorage`:

```
function load_data(){
    let table_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('table_data'));
    for (i = 1; i < table_data.length/3; i++) $("#addrow").click()
    $('.form-control').each(function(index) {$(this).val(table_data[index])});
}
```

This function loads data from `localStorage` using `getItem` function.
The loaded data is a `String`, so it is converted into the array using `JSON.parse`.
Next, new rows are inserted according to the size of `table_data` array.
In the end, it iterates through all table cells and fills them with loaded data.
This function should be executed only after you the page is loaded and only if data exists in `localStorage`.The best way is to put this line at the bottom of `ready` function:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("table_data") != null) load_data()
```